# Multitenancy support when using Apache Camel and Hibernate (in a Spring application)

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-camel, multi-tenant, spring-camel

I have a Spring application which uses the Hibernate schema strategy and a `TenantContext` class to store the tenant identifier (same design shown here: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-database-schema-multitenancy/).

Everything works fine when dealing with synchronous HTTP requests handled by Spring.

Besides that, I have some Camel routes which are triggered by chron jobs. They use the JPA component to read from or write to a datasource. The `Exchange` object knows the tenant identifier. How to transfer that information to Hibernate?

I was thinking about using a listener or interceptor to get the tenant id from the `Exchange` and set the `TenantContext` object at every step in the route. The TenantContext will then be used by the Hibernate `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` class to resolve the tenant.

How should the `TenantContext` look like? Is it `ThreadLocal` a viable option? What about async threads?

In general, do you have any good solution to support Hibernate multitenancy when using Camel?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it depends on your use case ;)

But we have done something similar, [using a ThreadLocal in the CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver](https://gist.github.com/gdubya/c055ef8b394e17b7ac0b47a4c0f9f355).

Then in the places where we need to set the tenant (e.g. at the start of the job being executed by the cronjob, in your case), we have an instance of tenantIdentifierResolver used like so:

```
        tenantIdentifierResolver.withTenantId(tenant, () -> {
            try {
                doWhatever(param1, param2, etc);
            } catch (WhateverException we) {
                throw new MyBusinessException(we);
            }
        });
```